# The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit systems error

Tags: excel, vba, progress-bar

I've been making progress bar in VBA Excel along some tutorial on the internet and they gave code to handle pop-up window which is below:

```
'PLACE IN STANDARD MODULE
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

Public Const GWL_STYLE = -16
Public Const WS_CAPTION = &HC00000
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLong _
                           Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
                           ByVal hWnd As Long, _
                           ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLong _
                           Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" ( _
                           ByVal hWnd As Long, _
                           ByVal nIndex As Long, _
                           ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function DrawMenuBar _
                           Lib "user32" ( _
                           ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowA _
                           Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
                           ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#Else
    Public Declare Function GetWindowLong _
                           Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
                        ByVal hWnd As Long, _
                           ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function SetWindowLong _
                           Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" ( _
                           ByVal hWnd As Long, _
                           ByVal nIndex As Long, _
                           ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function DrawMenuBar _
                           Lib "user32" ( _
                           ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function FindWindowA _
                           Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
                           ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#End If
Sub HideTitleBar(frm As Object)
    Dim lngWindow As Long
    Dim lFrmHdl As Long
    lFrmHdl = FindWindowA(vbNullString, frm.Caption)
    lngWindow = GetWindowLong(lFrmHdl, GWL_STYLE)
    lngWindow = lngWindow And (Not WS_CAPTION)
    Call SetWindowLong(lFrmHdl, GWL_STYLE, lngWindow)
    Call DrawMenuBar(lFrmHdl)
End Sub
```

The bad news are that that chunk of code is red:

```
Public Declare Function GetWindowLong _
                       Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
                    ByVal hWnd As Long, _
                       ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function SetWindowLong _
                       Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" ( _
                       ByVal hWnd As Long, _
                       ByVal nIndex As Long, _
                       ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function DrawMenuBar _
                       Lib "user32" ( _
                       ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function FindWindowA _
                       Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
                       ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
```

And it spits out error: The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit
systems. Please review and update Declare statements and then
mark them with the PtrSafe attribute, when i try to do something with it. How can i handle this?

EDIT:
I added the Ptr in some places but I'm not sure if I've done it correctly. Can someone check please?

```
'PLACE IN STANDARD MODULE
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

Public Const GWL_STYLE = -16
Public Const WS_CAPTION = &HC00000
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtrA _
                           Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
                           ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
                           ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLongPtr _
                           Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" ( _
                           ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
                           ByVal nIndex As Long, _
                           ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function DrawMenuBar _
                           Lib "user32" ( _
                           ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Long
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowA _
                           Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
                           ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#Else
    Public Declare Function GetWindowLong _
                           Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
                        ByVal hWnd As Long, _
                           ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function SetWindowLong _
                           Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" ( _
                           ByVal hWnd As Long, _
                           ByVal nIndex As Long, _
                           ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function DrawMenuBar _
                           Lib "user32" ( _
                           ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function FindWindowA _
                           Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
                           ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#End If
Sub HideTitleBar(frm As Object)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim lngWindow As Long
    Dim lFrmHdl As Long
    lFrmHdl = FindWindowA(vbNullString, frm.Caption)
    lngWindow = GetWindowLongPtrA(lFrmHdl, GWL_STYLE)
    lngWindow = lngWindow And (Not WS_CAPTION)
    Call SetWindowLongPtr(lFrmHdl, GWL_STYLE, lngWindow)
    Call DrawMenuBar(lFrmHdl)
End Sub
```

Comment: The fact that it's red can actually be ignored. The bad news really is that the 64 bit compatible parts are mostly wrong. It takes more than just adding `PtrSafe` to all the calls. All the variables that are handles/pointers need to be declared as `LongPtr` not just `Long`

Comment: Worth to mention that **only** the variables/arguments that are handles/pointers should be changed to `LongPtr`. Turning every `Long` into `LongPtr` will not work neither.

Comment: This tool can help you: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/dennis/windowsapiviewer.htm

Comment: Note that for win64 it looks like the [GetWindowLongA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlonga) needs to be replaced by the [GetWindowLongPtrA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlongptra) if you are retrieving a pointer or a handle.